# ag-grid: getRows call twice when gridApi?.setServerSideDatasource(serverSideDatasource) only call once

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Our team is using "ag-grid-community": "29.2.0", "ag-grid-enterprise": "29.2.0", "ag-grid-react": "29.2.0". Now we have a feature about getting table B column headers and table B data from BE api dynamically when click a button from another table A (This two tables are one the same page but not parent-child relationship).
The issue is that it will call the `getRows()` method twice even though the method `gridApi?.setServerSideDatasource(serverSideDatasource)`only call once.
I tried solve this issue by setting `blockLoadDebounceMillis={true}` which doesn't work, I also tried to upgrade ag-grid to the latest version 30.0.0 which also doesn't work. Can you give me some suggestions about solving this issue?
code screenshot is as follows:

[code part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXauv.png)

[code part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJEpQ.png)

[code part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew5OL.png)

[code part4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooa0b.png)

[code part5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko4oT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.